# Why doesn't numpy allow broadcasting when a dimenison of first array is a multiple of corresponding dimension of second array?

Tags: python, numpy

Two dimensions are compatible when

- they are equal, or
- one of them is 1

Can't they also be made compatible if one of them is a multiple of another?

Consider the following example when shape of array A is (2,3) and shape of array B is (4,3):

`A = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]   B = [[11,12,13],[14,15,16],[17,18,19],[20,21,22]]`

For acheving `A + B`, we broadcast A to be of shape (4,3) by repeating the rows 2 (i.e 4/2) times.

So `A = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]`  and `A + B = [[12,14,16],[18,20,22],[18,20,22],[24,26,28]]`

Is the problem with this approach that it is not useful when dealing with real data ?

Comment: `broadcasting` is not done by simply repeating.  It depends on the unique qualities of a size 1 dimension, and its `strides`.  Details though are implemented in compiled code, so aren't readily available to us python level programmers.  You may get some insights by looking at the strides of broadcastable arrays.

Comment: Another consideration is clarity.  The broadcasting rules are simple and unambiguous. 1) add leading size 1 dimensions as needed, 2) adjust all size 1 dimensions to match (this is a `view` operations, not a repeat with copy).  (Ultimately "why" questions like this can only be answered with educated guesses - unless the relevant developer happens to be hanging around this board and sees your question today.)